# How do I adjust the position of sidebar in confluence?

Tags: confluence

We have a custom top menu as well as a sidebar on confluence. On some browsers the top part of the sidebar is eclipsed by the top menu. I want to move the sidebar down a little bit so it is below the top menu. I looked at confluence docs and while there are steps to customize sidebar, nothing mentions how we can move the sidebar down a little.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS to position the sidebar to where you want it. To add it (without writing a whole custom plugin), you can add CSS in the Administration menu in "Look and Feel" -> "Stylesheet" or alternatively "Custom HTML" -> "At the end of the head". You would need to add something like this (with the correct element ID or class of course):

```
#sidebar-id {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Surround that with a `<style>` tag if you are using the custom HTML variant.